# π Day puzzle for 3/14

Tags: popularity-contest, pi, polyglot

[image: xkcd π comic]

Happy π Day. The goal of this question is to calculate the area for a circle of radius 3, where A = πr².

The catch is that you have to use the constant π that is defined in a different language than the one you are programming in. For example, you can write a C program that uses Fortran's `MATH::PI`, or a Python program that uses Java's `java.lang.Math.PI`.

Rules:

- Your code must use a stored value of π from a different language for the calculation. (i.e. it must be stored in a constant or math library.)
- All of the code for your program must fit in a single file. For example, You cannot write one program in C to print π, then another in Java to run the C program. (However, you *can* write a Java program that writes and compiles a C program by itself.)
- You cannot download π from a webpage and claim that your constant came from PHP/ASP/HTML.

Here is an example that runs in Bash, and uses Python's stored `math.pi` value:

```
#!/bin/bash
PI=`python -c 'import math; print math.pi'`
bc -l <<< "3 * 3 * $PI"
```

Output:

```
28.27433388231
```

This is a Popularity Contest, so the entry with the most votes after a week wins.

**Edit:** After one week, the prize goes to DigitalTrauma with 93 points. Thanks for the awesome assembler tip - I did not know that the the FPU stored the constant in hardware. I expected this contest to be about finding funny ways to throw clock cycles away, but that one could actually save a few.

* Image courtesy of: http://xkcd.com/10/

Comment: It's the 3rd day of the 14th month?? My calendar must be broken.

Comment: You beat me to posting a Pi Day challenge :P

Comment: Next year: 3/14/15 at 9:26 and 53sec, i will post a challenge

Comment: Ugh. Tau is better. [And this.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5iUh_CSjaSw)

Comment: @bjb I agree, Tau makes more sense, but that doesn't mean we can't have a little fun in mid march. :)

Comment: @under [Whada you mean? There's National Pig Day!](http://www.holidayinsights.com/moreholidays/march.htm)

Comment: 22/7 is a better pi day.

Comment: I'm not sure what Pi day is, but this would have been excellent for Tau/2 day yesterday.

Comment: How intriguing. On π day, my reputation was 314.

Comment: @tbodt How intriguing.  On π day (and on all other days), a new user starts with a reputation of `314/314`.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1292/ (seriously, stop this tau silliness).

Comment: Have anyone spotted, that this time it is not only pi day but a pi month?

Comment: I really dislike this whole "pi day" thing because it focuses on the complete _wrong_ aspect of pi: its decimal radix form. Pi is important because it is the half period of exp(x*sqrt(-1)) WRT x, so pi day should be at the half periods of the tropical year, i.e. January 1st and July 2nd/3rd.

Comment: @TheDoctor Except, you didn't.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

## C + x86 assembly

Not satisfied with a constant defined in the software of your language?  Why not use a language that can access a constant value of PI right from your FPU hardware:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    double pi;
    __asm__("fldpi" : "=t" (pi));
    printf("%g\n", 3 * 3 * pi);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Holy crap, there's an instruction just to load the value of pi.

Comment: x86 has instructions for EVERYTHING.

Comment: @user2357112 There are 7 [instructions just for loading "commonly used constants"](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_101.html)

Comment: Good choices for the 7 constants, too! I'm always using log_e(2), but not, say, 2.

Comment: @TimS. My intuition tells me these FPU transistors would be better used for improving performance of say FDIV (and letting software load such constants from memory), rather than storing all these constants on the FPU.  But I'm not a chip designer - what do I know :)

Comment: @TimS. log_e(2) is not equal to log(exp(2)) = 2, but actually is the natural logarithm of 2...

Comment: @MathieuRodic yes, but the point is that `fld qword [2.0]` is a 9 byte instruction, and `fldln2` is a two byte instruction. The irony of @TimS.' comment is that there's plenty of constants that would have been more useful, such as -1, or 2.

Comment: @fluffy my x86 core is broken: I tried MOV AX, c0ffe; ADD MILK; ADD SUGAR; ADD SUGAR; MOV ecx, c0ffe; MOV ebx,1; MOV eax,4 and my bios speaker laughed at me.....

Comment: @GMasucci Your mistake was trying to use the general-purpose MOV instruction on the special coffee registers. You need to use the coffee-specific instructions.

Answer (score 80):

#### Python, bash, C, J, PHP and Python3

```py
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("""
echo '
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int pi) {
    if (pi == 1) printf("%.5f", M_PI);
    if (pi == 2) printf("o. 1");
    if (pi == 3) printf("<?php printf(\\"%%.5f\\", pi()); ?>");
    if (pi == 4) printf("import math; print(\\" %%.5f\\" %% math.pi)");
    return 0;
}
' > gcc -o pi
./pi
./pi J | jc
./pi and PHP | php
./pi and Python 3 | python3
""", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

values_of_pi = map(float, map(str.strip, p.stdout.read().split()))
pi = max(values_of_pi, key=values_of_pi.count)

print pi * 3 * 3
```

Just to be safe, this program retrieves pi from a few different languages, taking the most agreed upon value. More languages can easily be added for greater reliability.

Comment: I just threw up a little in my mouth.

Comment: What's J and why are you running your C program with it?

Comment: @NoBugs [J](http://www.jsoftware.com/) is another language, and I'm running it (`jc` is the J console on my computer) with output from my C program (`o. 1`) to get another value of pi. The arguments aren't important.

Comment: `echo $long_string > gcc -o pi`? I can't believe no one caught this. Also, have you heard of here-docs|here-strings?

Comment: This is one of the coolest pieces of code I have ever seen. I am going to frame this and put it on my wall. Possibly with a warning.

Answer (score 42):

## PHP/MYSQL

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "dbname");
$query = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT PI() AS pi');
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
echo 3*3*$row['pi'];
```

Comment: Very clever. Using a very standard way of interfacing different runtimes. =) +1

Answer (score 36):

### Perl/Tk with C, Pascal, Java, JavaScript, LaTeX3, Prolog, Perl, Scheme, Lua, Python, TeX/PGF

The following Perl script displays a windows that lists the values of π and the calculated area. The value of π is taken from different languages
as shown below.

[image: Result]

The one-file script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
$^W=1;

use Tk;
use Tk::Font;
use Tk::HList;
use Tk::ItemStyle;
use Tk::PNG;

# Function to calculate the area of the circle with radius 3
sub A ($) {
    use bignum;
    return 9*$_[0];
}

my $title = 'Pi Day';

# Configuration of external program names
my %prg = qw[
    Pascal fpc
    Perl perl
    Prolog swipl
    Scheme guile1
    TeX  tex
    LaTeX latex
];
sub prg ($) {
    my $prg = shift;
    return $prg{$prg} // $prg;
}

# Column headers
my @header = (
    '',
    'Language',
    "\N{U+03C0}",
    "A(3) = A(r) = \N{U+03C0}\N{U+2009}r\N{U+00B2}",
);

my $mw = MainWindow->new(
    -title => $title,
);

# Font setup (larger font)
my $font_size = '22';
my $font = $mw->Font();
$font->configure(-size => $font_size);

# ---------
# Utilities
# ---------

# Run program in backticks, quote arguments if needed and some error checking
sub backticks_pi (@) {
    my @cmd = map{/[ ()$;<>|\x22]/ && length > 1 ? "'$_'" : $_} @_;
    print "[@cmd]\n";
    my $catch = `@cmd`;
    if ($? == -1) {
        warn "Failed to execute: $!\n";
    }
    elsif ($? & 127) {
        warn sprintf "Child died with signal %d!\n", $? & 127;
    }
    elsif ($?) {
        warn sprintf "Child exited with value %d!\n", $? >> 8;
    }
    else {
        return $1 if $catch =~ /^\s*(\d+\.\d+)\s*$/
                  or $catch =~ /\bpi\s*=\s*(\d+\.\d+)/;
    }
    warn "Could not find pi in the output of \"@cmd\"!\n";
    return 0;
}

# Run a program with error checking
sub run_cmd (@) {
    print "[@_]\n";
    system @_;
    if ($? == -1) {
        warn "Failed to execute: $!\n";
    }
    elsif ($? & 127) {
        warn sprintf "Child died with signal %d!\n", $? & 127;
    }
    elsif ($?) {
        warn sprintf "Child exited with value %d!\n", $? >> 8;
    }
    else {
        return $1;
    }
    return undef;
}

# Create a bitmap logo
sub make_logo ($$$@) {
    my $name = shift;
    my $logo = shift;
    my $contents = shift;
    my $file = "piday-logo-$name.tmp";
    if ($contents) {
        open(OUT, '>', $file) or die "!!! Error: Cannot write `$file': $!";
        print OUT $contents;
        close(OUT);
    }
    foreach (@_) {
        run_cmd @$_;
    }
    return $mw->Photo(
        -file => $logo,
    ) if -f $logo;
    return undef;
}

# Call foreign language to calculate pi
sub make_pi ($$@) {
    my $file = shift;
    my $source = shift;
    if ($source) {
        open(OUT, '>', $file) or die "!!! Error: Cannot write `$file': $!";
        print OUT $source;
        close(OUT);
    }
    my $cmd_last = pop;
    foreach (@_) {
        run_cmd @$_;
    }
    return backticks_pi @$cmd_last;
}

# Add result list table
my $h = $mw->HList(
    -header  => 1,
    -columns => scalar @header,
    -width   => 100,
    -height  => 20,
    -font    => $font,
)->pack(
  -expand => 1,
  -fill => 'both',
);

# Add header for the result list table
for (0 .. @header-1) {
    $h->header('create', $_,
        -text => $header[$_],
    );
}

# Exit button
my $quit = $mw->Button(
    -text => 'Quit',
    -command => sub {exit},
    -font => $font,
)->pack;


my @list;
my @cmd;
my $pi;
my $source;
my $img;

# GNU C
# -----

$img = make_logo(
    'C',
    'piday-logo-c.png',
    '',
    [
        prg('wget'),
        '-O', 'piday-logo-c-gccegg.png',
        'http://gcc.gnu.org/img/gccegg-65.png',
    ],
    [
        prg('convert'),
        '-scale', '54x64',
        'piday-logo-c-gccegg.png',
        'piday-logo-c.png',
    ],
);

$source = <<'END_SOURCE';
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define xstr(s) str(s)
#define str(s) #s

int main() {
  long double pi = M_PI;
  printf("pi=%s", xstr(M_PIl));
  return 0;
}
END_SOURCE

$pi = make_pi(
    'piday-c.c',
    $source,
    [
        prg('gcc'),
        '-o', 'piday-c',
        'piday-c.c',
    ],
    [
        prg('./piday-c')
    ],
);

push @list, {
    language => 'GNU C',
    pi       => $pi,
    image    => $img,
};

# Java
# ----

$img = make_logo(
    'Java',
    'piday-java.png',
    '',
    [
        prg('wget'),
        '-O', 'piday-java.svg',
        'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/Java_logo_and_wordmark.svg',
    ],
    [
        prg('convert'),
        '-scale', '35x64',
        'piday-java.svg',
        'piday-java.png',
    ],
);

$source = <<'END_SOURCE';
public class PiDayJava {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(Math.PI);
    }
}
END_SOURCE

$pi = make_pi(
    'PiDayJava.java',
    $source,
    [
        prg('javac'),
        'PiDayJava.java',
    ],
    [
        prg('java'),
        'PiDayJava',
    ],
);
push @list, {
    language => 'Java',
    pi       => $pi,
    image    => $img,
};

# Perl
# ----

# Math/Complex.pm: sub pi () { 4 * CORE::atan2(1, 1) }
@cmd = (prg('Perl'), '-e', 'use Math::Complex; print pi');
$pi = backticks_pi @cmd;

my $img = Tk->findINC('Camel.xpm');
$img = $mw->Photo(
    -file => $img,
);

push @list, {
    language => 'Perl',
    pi => $pi,
    image => $img,
};

# Python
# ------

@cmd = (
    prg('echo'),
    'import math;print math.pi',
    '|',
    prg('python'),
);
$pi = backticks_pi @cmd;

$img = make_logo(
    'python',
    'piday-logo-python.png',
    '',
    [
        prg('wget'),
        '-O',
        'piday-logo-python-master.png',
        'http://www.python.org/static/community_logos/python-logo-master-v3-TM.png',
    ],
    [
        prg('convert'),
        '-crop', '111x111+79+33',
        'piday-logo-python-master.png',
        'piday-logo-python-crop.png'
    ],
    [
        prg('convert'),
        '-scale', '64x64',
        'piday-logo-python-crop.png',
        'piday-logo-python.png',
    ],
);

push @list, {
    language => 'Python',
    pi => $pi,
    image => $img,
};

# TeX
# ---

@cmd = (
    prg('TeX'),
    '\input pgf \pgfmathparse{pi}\message{pi=\pgfmathresult}\end',
);
$pi = backticks_pi @cmd;
my $img = make_logo(
    'tex',
    'piday-logo-tex.png',
    '',
    [
        prg('pdftex'),
        '\mag=4000 \nopagenumbers\font\sc=cmcsc10 \sc pgf\bye'
    ],
    [
        prg('pdfcrop'),
        'texput.pdf',
        'piday-logo-tex.pdf',
    ],
    [
        prg('convert'),
        'piday-logo-tex.pdf',
        'piday-logo-tex.png',
    ]
);
push @list, {
    language => 'TeX/PGF',
    pi => $pi,
    image => $img,
};

# LaTeX3
# ------

my $logo_source = <<'END_LOGO';
\mag=4000
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hologo}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\hologo{LaTeX3}
\end{document}
END_LOGO

$img = make_logo(
    'latex3',
    'piday-logo-latex3.png',
    $logo_source,
    [
        prg('pdflatex'),
        'piday-logo-latex3.tmp'
    ],
    [
        prg('pdfcrop'),
        'piday-logo-latex3.pdf',
        'piday-logo-latex3-crop.pdf',
    ],
    [
        prg('convert'),
        'piday-logo-latex3-crop.pdf',
        'piday-logo-latex3.png',
    ]
);
$source = <<'END_LATEX3';
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_term:n { pi=\fp_eval:n { pi } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\stop
END_LATEX3
$pi = make_pi(
    'piday-latex3.tex',
    $source,
    [
        prg('LaTeX'),
        'piday-latex3.tex',
    ],
);
push @list, {
    language => 'LaTeX3',
    pi => $pi,
    image => $img,
};

print "****************\n";

# Lua
# ---

$img = make_logo(
    'Lua',
    'piday-logo-lua.png',
    '',
    [
        prg('wget'),
        '-O', 'piday-logo-lua.gif',
        'http://www.lua.org/images/lua-logo.gif',
    ],
    [
        prg('convert'),
        '-scale', '64x64', # '50x50',
        'piday-logo-lua.gif',
        'piday-logo-lua.png',
    ],
);

$source = 'print(math.pi)';
$pi = make_pi(
    'piday-lua.lua',
    $source,
    [
        prg('texlua'),
        'piday-lua.lua',
    ]
);
push @list, {
    language => 'Lua',
    pi => $pi,
    image => $img,
};

# JavaScript
# ----------

$img = make_logo(
    'JavaScript',
    'piday-logo-javascript.png',
    '',
    [
        prg('wget'),
        '-O', 'piday-logo-rhino.jpg',
        'https://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/832/=Rhino.jpg',
    ],
    [
        prg('convert'),
        '-scale', '127x64',
        'piday-logo-rhino.jpg',
        'piday-logo-javascript.png',
    ],
);

$source = 'print(Math.PI)';
$pi = backticks_pi(
    prg('java'),
    '-cp', prg('js.jar'),
    'org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main',
    '-e', $source,
);
push @list, {
    language => 'JavaScript',
    pi => $pi,
    image => $img,
};

# Scheme
# ------

$img = make_logo(
    'Scheme',
    'piday-logo-scheme.png',
    '',
    [
        prg('wget'),
        '-O', 'piday-logo-lambda.svg',
        'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Lambda_lc.svg',
    ],
    [
        prg('convert'),
        '-scale', '64x64',
        'piday-logo-lambda.svg',
        'piday-logo-scheme.png',
    ],
);
$source = '(display (* 2 (acos 0)))';
$pi = backticks_pi(
    prg('Scheme'),
    '-c', $source,
);
push @list, {
    language => 'Scheme',
    pi => $pi,
    image => $img,
};

# Prolog
# ------

$img = make_logo(
    'Prolog',
    'piday-logo-prolog.png',
    '',
    [
        prg('wget'),
        '-O', 'piday-logo-swipl.png',
        'http://www.swi-prolog.org/icons/swipl.png',
    ],
    [
        prg('convert'),
        '-scale', '78x64',
        'piday-logo-swipl.png',
        'piday-logo-prolog.png',
    ],
);
$source = ":- format('~15f~n', [pi]).\n";
$pi = make_pi(
    'piday-prolog.pro',
    $source,
    [
        prg('Prolog'),
        '-c', 'piday-prolog.pro',
    ]
);
push @list, {
    language => 'Prolog',
    pi => $pi,
    image => $img,
};

# Pascal
# ------

$img = make_logo(
    'Pascal',
    'piday-logo-pascal.gif',
    '',
    [
        prg('wget'),
        '-O', 'piday-logo-pascal.gif',
        'http://www.freepascal.org/pic/logo.gif',
    ]
);
$source = <<'END_PASCAL';
program piday_pascal;

uses sysutils, math;

begin
  writeln(format('%.16f', [pi]));
end.
END_PASCAL
$pi = make_pi(
    'piday-pascal.pas',
    $source,
    [
        prg('Pascal'),
        'piday-pascal.pas',
    ],
    [
        prg('./piday-pascal'),
    ]
);
push @list, {
    language => 'Pascal',
    pi => $pi,
    image => $img,
};

# Sort and fill the table rows
@list = sort {
    my $diff = (length $b->{'pi'} <=> length $a->{'pi'});
    return $diff if $diff;
    return "\L$a->{'language'}\E" cmp "\L$b->{'language'}\E";
} @list;

foreach my $x (@list) {
    my $e = $h->addchild("");
    my $col = 0;
    if ($x->{'image'}) {
        $h->itemCreate($e, $col++,
            -itemtype => 'image',
            -image => $x->{'image'},
        );
    }
    else {
        $col++;
    }
    $h->itemCreate($e, $col++,
        -itemtype => 'text',
        -text => $x->{'language'},
    );
    $h->itemCreate($e, $col++,
        -itemtype => 'text',
        -text => $x->{'pi'},
    );
    $h->itemCreate($e, $col++,
        -itemtype => 'text',
        -text => A $x->{'pi'},
    );
}

MainLoop;

__END__
```

### Languages

The following list shows the languages and the code that is used to get π.

- **GNU C:** GNU extensions are used to get a higher precision of π.

  ```c
  #define _GNU_SOURCE
  #include <math.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  #define xstr(s) str(s)
  #define str(s) #s

  int main() {
      long double pi = M_PI;
      printf("pi=%s", xstr(M_PIl));
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- **Pascal:** Compiled with [Free Pascal](http://www.freepascal.org/).

  ```pascal
  program piday_pascal;

  uses sysutils, math;

  begin
    writeln(format('%.16f', [pi]));
  end.
  ```
- **Java:**

  ```
  public class PiDayJava {
      public static void main(String args[]) {
          System.out.println(Math.PI);
      }
  }
  ```
- **JavaScript:** [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino) is used for executing JavaScript.

  ```javascript
  print(Math.PI)
  ```
- **LaTeX3:**

  ```tex
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{expl3}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
  \msg_term:n { pi=\fp_eval:n { pi } }
  \ExplSyntaxOff
  \stop
  ```
- **Prolog:** [SWI Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/) is used as Prolog compiler.

  ```prolog
  :- format('~15f~n', [pi]).
  ```
- **Perl:** For fun and completeness.

  ```perl
  use Math::Complex;
  print pi;
  ```
- **Scheme:** The uses Scheme implementation is [GNU Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/).

  ```scheme
  (display (* 2 (acos 0)))
  ```
- **Lua:** [`texlua`](http://www.luatex.org/) is used as Lua interpreter.

  ```lua
  print(math.pi)
  ```
- **Python:**

  ```python
  import math
  print math.pi
  ```
- **TeX/PGF:** π is taken from its definition of package [pgf](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and plain TeX is used as TeX format:

  ```tex
  \input pgf
  \pgfmathparse{pi}
  \message{pi=\pgfmathresult}
  \end
  ```

Answer (score 16):

## [dg](http://pyos.github.io/dg/)

```
print ((import '/math/pi')*3**2)
```

How it works:

dg is a language that compiles to CPython bytecode. Conveniently, it's compatible with python libraries. `import` statements in dg return the object they're importing, so this program basically does this:

```
print (<PYTHON'S MATH.PI>*3**2)
```

<sup><sub>No, I don't expect any upvotes. :)</sub></sup>

Comment: Oopsy daisy, I think I upvoted ;)

Comment: By the way, this is the first thing I ever did in dg. Someone else used it for a golf question and linked to the same place I linked to in this answer. I read it and thought the language looked neat (despite the fact that I despise the doge meme) but didn't plan on using it until about an hour after learning about it, when I read this question and realized I could abuse it.

Comment: 5 hours ago, when I posted my first comment, this had but 1 upvote. I think people did take my comment seriously ;)

Or they just used yours.

Comment: "All the code must fit in a single line". At least _some_ people can read!

Comment: `<PYTHON'S MATH.PI>` Those `repr()` strings you get for functions and other objects that don't|can't define their `__repr__()`s to be valid reconstructions of themselves aren't actually…well…valid. Try `__import__('math').pi`.

Comment: Was going to do the same thing with Scala as it is not Java ;-)

Comment: Wow. Much code. So pi.

Answer (score 15):

### C++ & Lua 5.2

Nothing says overkill quite like embedding an entire language interpreter to access the pi constant.

```cpp
#include <lua.hpp>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

#define R 3

int main( void )
{
    lua_State* vm = luaL_newstate();

    luaL_openlibs( vm );
    luaL_dostring( vm, "function get_pi() return math.pi end" );
    lua_getglobal( vm, "get_pi" );
    lua_call( vm, 0, 1 );

    lua_Number PI_ = lua_tonumber( vm, -1 );

    std::cout << PI_ * pow( R, 2 ) << std::endl;

    lua_close( vm );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could've just... `lua_getglobal("math");lua_getfield(-1,"pi");`

Comment: @mniip I realized that after I posted. It's early in the morning and my brain isn't fully operational yet, but this way works just as well so I left it alone.

Answer (score 13):

## bash + PHP + bc

A fairly simple one-liner:

```
echo "scale=14;3*3*`php -r 'echo pi();'`"|bc
```

Output:

```
28.274333882308
```

Comment: "All the code must fit in a single line". At least _some_ people can read!

Comment: @Floris: Hate to break it to you, but the question says *file*, not *line*.

Comment: @dennis - apparently I am not "some people"... :-/

Answer (score 10):

## MATLAB + Java (21 bytes)

Not sure if MATLAB is cheating, but here we go

```
java.lang.Math.PI*3^2
```

Output: `Format Short`

```
28.2743
```

Output: `Format Long`

```
28.2743338823081
```

Formatting type does not affect the value that is stored, it only impacts how it is printed out into the console

Comment: MATLAB.. -*shudders*-

Comment: @theGreenCabbage haha, not sure if that is a good shudder or a bad one :) In my experience it has made writing simple things quickly very easy. Of course there are better alternatives, but if there is not a lot of time, MATLAB does the trick.

Answer (score 10):

## Bash, Node, Ruby, Python

```sh
#!/bin/bash

node -pe 'Math.PI' \
| ruby -e 'puts ARGF.read.to_f * 3' \
| python -c 'import sys; print(float(sys.stdin.read()) * 3)'
```

Answer (score 7):

## perl

```
perl -ne '/M_PI\s*([\d.]*)/&&print $1*3*3' < /usr/include/math.h
```

Comment: +1, even though it doesn't actually work in OS X (math.h includes other files from `architecture/*/math.h` depending on the target platform)

Comment: Well it doesn't work on Windows either, but I'm not going for portability here :)

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript/PHP

Has to be saved as a *.php file and called in a browser from some server which interprets PHP.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(3*3*<?php echo M_PI;?>);
</script>
```

Could be golfed by using short tags and substituting 3*3 with 9 (is this allowed?):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(9*<?=M_PI?>);
</script>
```

pi() has the same length as M_PI, so there's no winner.

Comment: "is this allowed"  - sure, it's not code golf but popularity contest.

Comment: This will not run neither in php nor javascript though.

Comment: Yeah, it needs some `<script>` tags and a .php extension.

Comment: I edited it although I think it was understandable enough...

Comment: @Cthulhu "Has to be saved as a *.php file and called in a browser from some server which interprets PHP." Using pure .html or .php or .whatever files won't work, you need apache or something like that.

Answer (score 7):

### Powershell + MS SQL Server

Here is one for Powershell and SQL server (from 2005 up)

```
add-pssnapin sqlserverprovidersnapin100
add-pssnapin sqlservercmdletsnapin100
$pi=Invoke-Sqlcmd -query "select PI() as sql"
$pi.sql *3*3
```

and here as a single liner:

```
add-pssnapin sqlserverprovidersnapin100;add-pssnapin sqlservercmdletsnapin100;(Invoke-Sqlcmd -query "select PI() as sql").sql*3*3
```

Will post some more later on:)

Answer (score 6):

### Emacs Lisp: writing, compiling, and running C

```lisp
(with-temp-buffer
  (with-temp-file"/#rad.c"(insert"#include<math.h>\n#include<stdio.h>\nint main(void){printf(\"%f\",M_PI*3*3);}"))
  (shell-command"gcc /#rad.c -o /#rad && /#rad"(current-buffer))(string-to-number(buffer-string)))
```

ungolfed

```lisp
(with-temp-buffer
  (with-temp-file "/#rad.c"
    (insert"
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
  printf(\"%f\",M_PI*3*3);
}"))
  (shell-command "gcc /#rad.c -o /#rad && /#rad"
         (current-buffer))
  (string-to-number(buffer-string)))
```

bonus:

You could triple language this one by running emacs in batch using -eval and surrounding the expression in `(print)`. This would result in Bash running lisp which writes compiles and runs C reads the output and prints it out to your shell in bash.

Answer (score 5):

For this question, I created my own language,called Digits. The syntax consists of p, a constant representing pi, and digits. When run, it returns all of the digits (and p) multiplied together. Here is my interpreter and code, written in Python:

```
def interpret(kode):
    out=1.0
    for i in kode:
        if(i=='p'):
            out*=3.14159265
        else:
            out*=int(i)
    return out
print(interpret("p33"))
```

Comment: Looks to me more like a function in Python than a language, but it works.

Comment: @hosch250 The python interpreter itself is a (set of) function written in C (in the case of CPython) so this answer is very valid. Quite clever I would say.

Answer (score 4):

## bc + dc + bash (30 chars for the golfers)

Here's a golfy little one:

```
$ dc<<<"3d*`bc -l<<<'a(1)*4'`*p"
28.27433388230813914596
$
```

- `bc -l<<<'a(1)*4'` produces pi (it is stored as a constant in the bc math lib for the a() (arctan) function.
- `dc<<<"3d*`pi`*p"` pushes 3 to the stack, duplicates the value on the top of the stack (3) and multiples, then pushes pi to the stack and multiples, then prints the top of the stack.

Answer (score 4):

## OCaml + awk

Nobody likes OCaml?

- Use OCaml to *compute* Pi
- `awk` to calculate Pi*r<sup>2</sup>

Here it is:

```
ocaml <<< "4.0 *. atan 1.0;;" | awk '/float/{printf("%.12f", 3*3*$NF)}'
```

The answer is:

```
28.274333882308
```

Answer (score 4):

## VimScript + Python

```
:py import math
:ec pyeval("math.py")*3*3
```

result:

```
28.274334
```

Answer (score 4):

## C++/C

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << 3*3*M_PI << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! But I think the question is looking for a program that actually calls a function or compiles a program in another language, not one that merely *will compile* in more than one language.

Comment: @JonathanVanMatre: I think in this case he meant that he uses constant from C header in C++. `std::cout` was never a valid C syntax.

Comment: Ah, good call there.

Answer (score 4):

Very simple, uses bash to access the C math library:

```
bc -l <<< "3 * 3 * `grep -w M_PI /usr/include/math.h | awk '{ print $4 }'`"
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Fortran does not actually have an intrinsic value for pi (which is was OP seems to indicate with the statement "Fortran's `MATH::PI`"), I had to write one for C. I opted, rather than actually defining it, that I'd just determine it using [some fast algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_algorithm):

```
#include <math.h>
double pi_eval(){
    double a = 1.0;
    double b = 1.0/sqrt(2.0);
    double t = 0.25;
    double x = 1.0;
    double y;
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<4; i++){
        y = a;
        a = 0.5*(a+b);
        b = sqrt(b*y);
        t -= x*(y-a)*(y-a);
        x *= 2.0;
    }
    return (a+b)*(a+b)/(4.0*t);
}
```

(saved as `pi_calc.c`) Which is then used in `area_calc.f90`:

```
program area_calc
   use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
   implicit none

   interface
     function pi_eval() bind(c)
       use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
       real(c_double) :: pi_eval
     end function pi_eval
   end interface
   real(c_double) :: pi, area

   pi = pi_eval()
   print *,"area=",3.0*3.0*pi

end program area_calc
```

This outputs the required

```
 area=   28.2743338823081
```

One compiles this using

```
gcc -c pi_calc.c
gfortran -o area pi_calc.o area_calc.f90
```

Answer (score 3):

## R & C++

Requires the `inline` and `Rcpp` packages in R.

```
get.pi <- inline::cxxfunction(plugin="Rcpp", includes="#include <cmath>", body="return wrap(M_PI);")

get.pi() * 3 ^ 2
```

`cxxfunction` creates, compiles and links a C++ function behind the scenes. Yes, there is quite a lot of code generation happening, and `return wrap(M_PI);` is C++ code (along with the `#include` part).

Answer (score 3):

## Java + JavaScript

```java
class Pi {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println((double) new javax.script.ScriptEngineManager()
                .getEngineByName("JavaScript").eval("Math.PI")
                * Math.pow(3, 2));
    }
}
```

```
28.274333882308138
```

Comment: You beat me to it. :(

Answer (score 3):

## Julia using Python

```
julia> using PyCall
julia> @pyimport math
julia> math.pi*3^2
28.274333882308138
```

That was fun, I'd never used PyCall before.  The interface is super easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

## R + grep + awk + dc

```
echo pi | R --no-save --quiet | grep -v '^>' | awk '{print $2}' | dc -e '?3 3 **p'
```

Output:

```
28.274337
```

Answer (score 3):

### Using Lua's π in Java

This program uses the library LuaJ to evaluate Lua in Java and get π. It also squares the area with Lua.
Enjoy!

```
    ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine se = sem.getEngineByName("luaj");
    se.eval("pi = math.pi");
    double pi = (double) se.get("pi");

    int r = 3;

    se.eval("radius = "+r);
    se.eval("rsquared = math.pow(radius, 2)");
    int rsquared = (int) se.get("rsquared");

    double area = pi * rsquared;
    System.out.println("For a circle with a diameter of "+r+", the area is "+area+".");
```

The output:

`For a circle with a diameter of 3, the area is 28.274333882308138.`

Answer (score 2):

## Jython + Java

This should work in Jython. I'm not sure, as I have no way to test it ATM.

```
from java.lang import Math
print Math.PI * 3 ** 2
```

Jython can access the Java libraries, so I can just import the Math class from java.lang and use its PI constant to calculate the area of the circle.

Golfed:

```
import java.lang.Math.PI;print PI*3*3
```

Or, if I'm allowed to code in 3^2:

```
import java.lang.Math.PI;print PI*9
```

Answer (score 2):

## bash (PI from perl,python,c)

Maybe if we combine everything we've got, we get a more accurate result? :)

```
#!/bin/bash
exec >&>(bc -l|tail -n1)
perl <<EOF
use Math::Trig;
print pi
EOF
echo -n +
python <<EOF
import sys
from math import pi
sys.stdout.write(str(pi))
EOF
echo -n +
cat > pi.c <<EOF
#include <math.h>
main(){printf("%.16f",M_PI);}
EOF
gcc pi.c -o pi &>/dev/null
./pi
rm -f pi pi.c
echo ";"
echo "(last/3)*3.^2"
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby+Python

```
puts `python -c "from math import pi; print pi"`.to_f * 3**2
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML + PHP

```
<html><body>
value of area of circle is <br>
<?php echo 3*3*M_PI; ?>
</body></html>
```

Confused whether it satisfy the 3rd rule. but since M_PI is already used so it should count.

Answer (score 2):

## **ACTIONSCRIPT3 + javascript(using parse.com)**

```
Parse.CFunction('getPi',{},function(returned){trace(3*3*returned.result)});
```

parse class link https://github.com/camdagr8/AS3-Parse-Class/blob/master/com/illumifi/Parse.as

with code:

```
public static function CFunction(className:String, params:Object = null, success:Function = null, error:Function = null) {
            var url:String = Parse.api + "functions/" + className;
            Parse.Call(url, URLRequestMethod.POST, params, null, success, error);
        }
```

parse main.js:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getPi", function(request, response) {
  response.success(Math.PI);
});
```

result:

```
28.274333882308138
```

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica + R

```
Needs["RLink`"]
InstallR[]
 = REvaluate["pi"][[1]];
R = 3;
 R^2
```

Answer (score 2):

## bash + html + APL

```
 echo '<html><body><p>&#x25cb;3*2</p></body></html>' | w3m -dump -T text/html | apl -f -
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok I'll bite...

## AWK + PHP

```
$ awk -v PI=`php -r 'echo pi();'` 'BEGIN{print 3*3*PI}'
```

## PHP + AWK

```
$ php -r "echo 3*3*`awk 'BEGIN{printf 4*atan2(1,1)}'`;"
```

## BASH + PHP

```
$ PI=$(php -r 'echo pi();');C=$((${PI/\./}*3*3));echo ${C:0:2}.${C:2}
```

nJoy!

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby + Python + C++ + Batch (if you want to include it)

Oh, this took much longer than I wanted it to. As far as I know this will only work on Windows, though if you edit the `rm` command it may work on Linux.

Here's what it does:

1. Ruby creates pi.cpp
2. Ruby runs batch code to compile pi.cpp using MinGW or GCC
3. Ruby runs pi.exe
4. Pi.exe runs Python code to find pi
5. Python saves pi to pi.txt
6. Ruby reads pi.txt, does the math to find the area, and prints it

Comment out the last line to see the remnants of the process.

```
p = "\\\"import math; import subprocess; f = open('pi.txt', 'w'); print(math.pi, file=f)\\\""

c = '''#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() 
{ 
    system("python -c '''+p+'''");
    return(0);
}'''

command2 = "g++ pi.cpp -o pi.exe"
command3 = "pi.exe"
command4 = "rm pi.cpp && rm pi.exe && rm pi.txt"

File.open("pi.cpp", "w+") do |file|
    file.puts c
end

system(command2)
system(command3)

my_very_own_pi = ''

File.open("pi.txt", "r") do |file|
    my_very_own_pi = file.gets
end

puts "The answer is: #{(3**2)*(my_very_own_pi.to_f())}"

system(command4)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Obligatory GolfScript+Ruby answer :)

```
"#{Math::PI*9}"
```

Answer (score 1):

### ASP.net / JS

```
alert(3*3*<%Response.Write(Math.PI)%>)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab & Python

```
[~, pi] = system('python -c "import math; print(math.pi)"');
area = str2num(pi) * 3^2;
disp(area)
```

Output:

```
28.274333882308138
```

Answer (score 1):

### Groovy + Java  (Someone had to do it... :) )

```
println java.lang.Math.PI * 3 * 3
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML + JAVASCRIPT

```
<label>Price 1</label><input type="text" class="price" /><br/>
<label>Price 1</label><input type="text" class="price" /><br/>
<label>Total</label><input type="text" id="total" /><br/>
<script>
var $prices=$('.price').keyup(calcTotal);
function calcTotal(){
  var tot=Math.PI;
  $prices.each(function(){
      tot*=$(this).val() | 0;
    });
   $('#total').val( tot);  
}
</script>
```

Comment: Umm, jQuery isn't a "language." You're using JavaScript's Math.PI from... JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

### Java & JavaScript

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        try {
            System.out.println((double)engine.eval("Math.PI") * 3 * 3);
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C# and VB.NET

This one creates a VB.NET assembly on the fly (using Microsoft CodeDom) to get the value of Pi. No need to invoke shells, external interpreters, or any of those other tricks. You get two languages, not just in a single process, but in a single thread!

```cs
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace PiDay2014CSharpConsole
{
    public class AreaCalculator
    {
        private double Pi()
        {
            StringBuilder vb = new StringBuilder();
            vb.AppendLine("Public Class PiDay");
            vb.AppendLine("    Public Function VbPi() As Double");
            vb.AppendLine("        Return System.Math.PI");
            vb.AppendLine("    End Function");
            vb.AppendLine("End Class");
            CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
            cp.GenerateExecutable = false;
            cp.GenerateInMemory = true;
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
            CodeDomProvider provider = new VBCodeProvider();
            CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, vb.ToString());
            var piDay = cr.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("PiDay");
            Type t = piDay.GetType();
            object result = t.InvokeMember("VbPi",
               BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance,
               null, piDay, null);
            return (double)result;
        }

        public double CalculateArea(double radius)
        {
            return Pi() * radius * radius;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AreaCalculator calc = new AreaCalculator();
            Console.Out.WriteLine("{0}", calc.CalculateArea(3.0));
            Console.In.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

`28.2743338823081`

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby+Python

```
require 'bigdecimal'
require 'bigdecimal/util'
File.open("pi.py", 'w') {|f| f.write("import math\nfrom decimal import *\ngetcontext().prec = 100\nprint Decimal(math.pi)") }
puts %x(python pi.py).to_d*3*3
%x(rm pi.py)
```

result:

```
0.28274333882308138043981671216897666454315185546875E2
```

Comment: Python and Java?  Please specify the language in your title as `#Language#`

Answer (score 0):

**x86 Assembly Language**

NASM syntax

```
global _start

section .data
val: dq 3.0

section .text

_start:

fldpi
fld qword [val]
fmul st0,st0
fmul st1,st0
```